# printing user documents in grails

Tags: grails, printing, pretty-print

I'm working on an application that has to print invoices.
By now I do this by writing the needed variables from my application to an excel file, leave the application, open a word document that merges in the excel file before printing.

I think there should be a smarter way in grails.

who knows about it ?

Comment: Did you look at if there is any [plugins](https://grails.org/plugins/) that might help?

Comment: yes I did and found grails rendering plugin and grails pdf plugin, but I do not understand how to use any of the two.

Comment: in the meantime I found a good Tutorial for grailsrendering plugin here [link](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/09/grails-how-do-i-render-gsp-files-in-pdf.html)